# how to see events parameters in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I would like to see the most searched word in my android app.
this is my snippet

> ```
>     Bundle params = new Bundle();
>     params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SEARCH_TERM, term);
>     params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, getClass().getSimpleName());
>     mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SEARCH, params);
> ```

but in Firebase Analytics --> Events it only show me up the Event name "search", and when I click it for more details, I only see those cards without any reference to the event parameters with their counts.
[image]

Comment: It takes around 24Hours to populate the data, you can use `DebugView` to see if the events are correctly fired. More info. here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview